# How to set and get line series color from WinRT XAML Toolkit chart

Tags: xaml, windows-8, charts, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml-toolkit

**ANSWER**

Thanks Filip, finally I found way to set the color. I just need to add `Background` property in `DataPointStyle`. I am posting my answer here. Also found a way how to modify the default tooltip.

[Showing lines with different colors on a Silverlight Toolkit’s LineChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487145/showing-lines-with-different-colors-on-a-silverlight-toolkits-linechart)

[Using a custom ToolTip in Silverlight charting](http://deekodev.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/using-a-custom-tooltip-in-silverlight-charting/)

```
<charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="17" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="17" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value,Converter={StaticResource MyConv},ConverterParameter=TEST}"/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Lime" Stroke="Lime" StrokeThickness="3" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

---

**Question 1**

I am creating multiple line chart series in a chart. Now WinRT XAML Toolkit assigns color for each series in random manner. I am using custom style for data points, so when I use custom style that randomness of color goes off. So how can I set or get that random color of series ? If I can get the color then I can use that color in datapoint, and if I can set color then I will generate random color myself.

**Question 2**

Moreover while hovering over data points the tool tip shows the dependent value, but I want to show more details how can I achieve that ?

Here's my code with custom style.

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="LineChart" Title="Line Chart" Margin="70,0">
    <charting:LineSeries
                Title="Population 1"
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                IsSelectionEnabled="True">
            <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="17" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="17" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                                <Ellipse Fill="Green" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="3" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </charting:LineSeries>

    <charting:LineSeries
            Title="Population 2"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" Foreground="Blue">
        <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="17" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="17" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </charting:LineSeries>
</charting:Chart>
```

Chart with random color (NO CUSTOM DATAPOINT STYLE)

[image]

Chart with NO random color (WITH CUSTOM DATAPOINT STYLE) [You can see both line has yellow color]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to Bing for [silverlight toolkit chart custom line color](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=silverlight%20toolkit%20chart%20custom%20line%20color) yields some potentially useful pages, like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd433476.aspx). It should work mostly the same with the WinRT XAML Toolkit, but where they customize the Silverlight-based templates - you would need to customize the WinRT XAML Toolkit-based ones that you can either try to extract with Blend/Visual Studio designer or get the original templates from the source that you can grab from [CodePlex](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).